# How to deny access to specific pages with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I send a 404 page error for specific pages that exist on the web server? (Using htaccess).

For example, I have a config.php file and when I go to localhost/config.php it just shows a blank white page with nothing in it. I want it to appear as a 404 page, like the page doesn't exist.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want to return a 404 Not Found then you can use mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^config\.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

---

However, to "deny" access, and send a 403 Forbidden, then it would be preferable to use the following (core) directives on Apache 2.4:

```
<Files "config.php">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

You can achieve the same with mod_rewrite by using the `F` (`forbidden`) flag. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^config\.php$ - [F]
```

(The `L` flag is not required in this instance, since it is implied.)

Comment: Hi @w3dk, thank you so much! I used `RewriteRule ^config\.php$ - [R=404,L]` and it works for localhost/config.php - shows 404 page. when I add a trailing slash (localhost/config.php/) it doesn't show the 404 page, but a blank white page. What am I supposed to add to the code? Thanks :D

Comment: You can simply remove the `$` from the end of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to match all requests that _start_ `/config.php`. eg. `RewriteRule ^config\.php - [R=404,L]`. That additional slash (and anything that follows it) is called trailing _pathname information_. This can be disabled on the server, with the directive `AcceptPathInfo Off`, so that all URLs that contain additional path info result in a 404 - although that may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! @w3dk